# How to Convert a nested array to an object

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I want to create an object from a nested array only 2 levels deep.  The function I came up with returns

`[{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }]`

rather than

`[{ key1: 'value1' }, {key2: 'value2' }]`

I've also tried replacing the if statement with `obj[elem[0]] = elem[1];` but get the same result.

How can I create separate objects for each nested array?

```
var array = [["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]]

function nestedArrToObj(array){

  let obj = {};

  for (let i=0; i < array.length;i++) {
    let elem = array[i];

    if (!(obj[elem[0]])) {
      obj[elem[0]] = elem[1]
    }
  }

  return [obj];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the function `map`

```js
let array = [["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]];
let result = array.map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Using the function `reduce`

```js
let array = [["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]];
let result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  let [key, value] = c;
  return [...a, {[key]: value}];
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Cross-browser and backend technology compatible approach:**

```js
var array = [["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]];

var result = [];
for(var a of array) {
  var value = a.pop();
  var key = a.pop();
  
  var object = {};
  object[key] = value;
  
  result.push(object);
}

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I appreciate the response but I was trying to get each nested array as a __separate__ object

Comment: So for the answer using `reduce` in this line - `let [key, value] = c;`  - you can "unpack" the array in c as separate array objects?  like I could use `c[0]` in place of key in your answer?

Comment: @e1v1s that's called Destructuring assignment, basically get the index 0 and 1 and assign those values to `key` and `value` - [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Actually, `map` is more appropriate here than reduce, because it's an N->N and not N->1 transform.

Comment: @georg you're right, I updated the answer.  It's really straightforward with function `map`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version with `map`:

```js
console.log(
  [["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]]
      .map(x => {let obj = {}; obj[x[0]] = x[1]; return obj;})
)
```

Comment: Yep, `.map` is correct here, In ES6: `a.map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))`

Comment: @georg thanks! I was looking for how to assign the key like that, lol

Answer (score 0):

Some of the newer features of the language make this a bit easier. This is an ES5 solution.

```js
var array = [["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]]

function nestedArrToObj(array){
  return array.reduce(function(previous, current) {
      let obj = {};
      obj[current[0]] = current[1];
      previous.push(obj);
      return previous;
  }, []);
}

console.log(nestedArrToObj(array))
```